# Recommended way to achieve `rescue-ensure` kind of functionality with Kiba?

Tags: kiba-etl

We have a Kiba pipeline where we need to do some task after the job has ended, no matter if there were errors or not (the whole pipeline doesn't fail, we just have couple of validation errors or similar).

This is what the documentation says:

> :warning: Post-processors won't get called if an error occurred before them.
> https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki/Implementing-pre-and-post-processors

Would this be recommended way to do this:

```rb
Kiba.run(
  Kiba.parse do
    source(...)
    transform(...)
    destination(....)

    post_process do
      # we cannot do it here, because it won't get called
    end
  end
)

# is this the location to do it?
Job.some_special_cleanup_task
```

Thanks!

PS what does it mean:

> Post-processors won't get called if an error occurred before them.

Does this mean if the error occurred and wasn't rescued from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `post_process` will not be called in case of errors, as documented and as you pointed out!

At this point, the best solution is to use a form of `ensure` statement:

A common way to structure that is:

```rb
module ETL
  module Job
    module_function

    def setup(config)
      Kiba.parse do
        source(...)
        transform(...)
        destination(....)
      end
    end

    def some_special_cleanup_task
      # ...
    end

    def run(job)
      Kiba.run(job)
    ensure
      Job.some_special_cleanup_task
    end
  end
end
```

Doing so allows to keep the code for the always-run task close to the ETL job, which is nice.

If your task is instead very independent from the job, and you want to encourage reuse between jobs, you can also create a generic block-form component:

```rb
module ETL
  module Middlewares
    module CommonTask
      module_function

      def with_common_task
        yield
      ensure
        do_the_common_task
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which you would use like this:

```rb
ETL::Middlewares::CommonTask.with_common_task do
  Kiba.run(...)
end
```

This second form is used by [Kiba Pro FileLock](https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki/File-Lock), for instance.

In the future, Kiba ETL will introduce a form of middleware to make this even easier.